# How to disable “sender non-delivery notification” in postfix?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I understand that changing the following line to read "discard" instead of "bounce" in master.cf will prevent non-delivery notifications, but I'm wondering if it's possible to take it a step further and only disable non-delivery notifications originating from emails that have been blacklisted through a sender access list which is called through smtpd_recipient_restrictions in main.cf.

```
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is probably from [How do I configure Postfix to never send NDR responses?](http://know.mailsbestfriend.com/how_to_disable_ndr_responses_in_postfix--609264775.shtml). It says:

> It is strongly suggested that you do not disable NDR responses on any
> mail server. However, it is possible to disable NDR responses in
> Postfix if you would like to.

Let me explain. Your urge to disable *Non-Delivery Notifications* (NDN) aka *bounces messages* probably arises from a good intent to avoid sending *backscatter*. Still, you need to be able to inform your own users if they are sending mail to email addresses with problems. To achieve this, you need to divide SMTP server users into two categories and treat them differently:

1. **Local users should receive NDN**. Otherwise they'll think their mail were received even if they have mistyped the address, the address was changed, mailbox was full etc. Local users may exists on the same server or they might have permission to use this server as a relay.
2. **External users** trying to send mail to users on this server should not receive NDN messages. Instead, you should use ***connection-stage rejection*** if the recipient doesn't exist, the sender envelope address fails anti-forgery checks (SPF, DKIM, DMARC) or sender is on a block list (either the domain of the envelope address or the mail server's IP address). The responsibility to inform users about this error code & message given during the SMTP connection is on the sending MTA, which should act exactly like explained in #1. (Spambots won't care of this.)

Now, Postfix works just like this, if you only have configured it correctly i.e. it should not be an *open relay*. It usually does most of this by default, if you haven't messed with these default configuration parameters (from [Postfix Basic Configuration](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html)):

> - By default, Postfix will forward mail from clients in authorized network blocks to any destination. Authorized networks are defined
>   with the `mynetworks` configuration parameter.
> - By default, Postfix will forward mail from strangers (clients outside authorized networks) to authorized remote destinations only.
>   Authorized remote destinations are defined with the `relay_domains`
>   configuration parameter. The default is to authorize all domains (and
>   subdomains of the domains) listed with the `mydestination` parameter.

What you need to configure by hand is the further limitations for sender access, as the default for [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) is *empty*. Personally I like to combine all restrictions (including sender and [`smtpd_helo_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_helo_restrictions) HELO restrictions) to be part of [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions). They all are still effective from there, but the checks are performed after all the three (`HELO`, `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO`) commands are fully exchanged, making it easier to debug from logs, if something goes wrong.

Here's an example configuration for some basic checks you could perform. (Notice the comments.)

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,

    # Personal tables, only use if you have added these files.
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access/denied_recipients,
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access/sender_access,
    check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/access/client_access.cidr,

    # SPF anti-forgery checks. Requires external SPF service.
    check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf,

    # To minimize unnecessary use, add DNSBLs AFTER basic checks, e.g.
    reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,

    permit
```